# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table (code 1)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm getting this error of being unable to find the table.

I tried the solutions found through surfing like erasing the database in the emulator, but it didn't work.

I think it is related to reading a database from a different class, but I don't know how to manage this.

p.s. I'm currently using the sample provided by Android Studio '*SlidingTabsBasic*'

> **SlidingTabsBasicFragment.java**

```
public class SlidingTabsBasicFragment extends Fragment {

static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";

final String[] genre = {"고전문학", "b", "c", "d", "e","f","g","h","i","j" };

String[] genre1;

final String[] genre2 = {"...","3","4","5"};

SQLiteDatabase db;
MySQLiteOpenHelper helper;


...



class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

...

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity(), MainActivity.DATABASE_NAME, null, MainActivity.DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        String sql_genre1 = "select name from " + MySQLiteOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME +
                "";

        Cursor cursor_genre1 = db.rawQuery(sql_genre1,null); // where problem occurs

        if (cursor_genre1!=null){
             int count_genre1 = cursor_genre1.getCount();

             String[] temparray_genre1 = new String[count_genre1+1];

            temparray_genre1[0]="...";

            for (int i=1; i<=count_genre1 ; i++){

                temparray_genre1[i] = cursor_genre1.getString(0);
                cursor_genre1.moveToNext();
            }

            genre1 = temparray_genre1;

        }

...
```

> **MySQLiteOpenHelper.java**

```
package com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  final static public String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "LDB";

  public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    createTable(db);
    insertData(db);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String sql = "drop table if exists database";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    onCreate(db);

}

public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql ="create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
            + "(name text,"
            + "author text,"
            + "genre text,"
            + "isBookmarked integer)";

    db.execSQL(sql);

}

public void insertData(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.beginTransaction();

    insertintoLDB(db,"공무도하가", "작자미상", "고대가요");
    insertintoLDB(db,"구지가","작자미상","고대가요");
    insertintoLDB(db,"해가","작자미상","고대가요");
    insertintoLDB(db,"정읍사","작자미상","고대가요");
    insertintoLDB(db,"황조가","유리왕","고대가요");


    db.endTransaction();

}

public void insertintoLDB(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String author, String genre){
    String sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + "(name, author, genre, isBookmarked) "
            +"values('"+ name + "','" + author + "','" + genre + "',0)";

    db.execSQL(sql);
}
}
```

> **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LiteratureDatabase.db";

SQLiteDatabase db;
MySQLiteOpenHelper helper;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createDatabase();







    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public void createDatabase() {
    helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

> > **Logcat**

```
07-23 08:50:24.075  27205-27205/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic     E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic, PID: 27205
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: LDB (code 1): , while compiling: select name from LDB
```

Comment: The `onUpgrade` function uses the wrong table name.

Comment: @CL thanks, it does have an error there. But I still have the same error after fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an older version of the database on your device, which does have the (empty) database in place, but not the books table. If that's an option for you, just uninstall and reinstall the app.